How to make Heatmap with log y axis
I'm trying to represent particle size distribution with geom_tile, like this plot : [enter image description here]
(https://i.sstatic.net/zOGn9uT5.png)
My data represent concentration of particule for each bin of size and for each time. There is 137 bins of size per second.
So my df has 3 columns and 82337 rows. The first column is time from 10:45:00 to 10:56:00, then the numeric value of concentration per time (with value equal to 0 sometimes), and the numeric value of bin_column which represent bin size from 15 to 1375 per second. Here an example (I removed some lines)



Time
Bin_column
Concentration




10:45:00
15
1.583952e+04


10:45:00
25
5.800000e-01


10:45:00
1375
1.559140e+00


10:45:01
15
0.000000e+00



Here is my code :
library(ncdf4)
library(RNetCDF)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(patchwork)
library(ggpubr)
library(cowplot)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(chron)
library(scico)

files <- c(
  "base201204090056_2DS.nc",
  "base201204093146_2DS.nc",
  "base201204102044_2DS.nc",
  "base201204105249_2DS.nc",
  "base201204110956_2DS.nc",
  "base201204130416_2DS.nc",
  "base201204134204_2DS.nc",
  "base201204141637_2DS.nc",
  "base201204144715_2DS.nc",
  "base201204151055_2DS.nc"
)


diameter_h<- seconds_h <- bins<-mvd_all<-numeric()
concentration_h<-size_distrib_h<-matrix()

for (file in files) {
  nc_file <- nc_open(file)
  diameter_h<-c(diameter_h, ncvar_get(nc_file, nc_file$var[[294]]))
  size_distrib_h<-c(size_distrib_h, ncvar_get(nc_file, nc_file$var[[274]]))
  mvd_all<-c(mvd_all, ncvar_get(nc_file, nc_file$var[[285]]))
  seconds_h<-c(seconds_h, ncvar_get(nc_file, nc_file$var[[298]]))
  concentration_h<-c(concentration_h, ncvar_get(nc_file, nc_file$var[[280]]))
  bins<-c(bins, ncvar_get(nc_file, nc_file$var[[272]]))
  nc_close(nc_file)
}

bins<-as.data.frame(bins)
mvd_all<-as.data.frame(mvd_all)
seconds_h<-as.data.frame(seconds_h)
diameter_h<-as.data.frame(diameter_h)
concentration_h<-as.data.frame(concentration_h)
size_distrib_h<-as.data.frame(size_distrib_h)

[...]                 


ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y =bin_column, fill = concentration_h)) +
  geom_tile()+
  scale_fill_scico(palette = 'batlow', trans = "log", labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)), breaks = c(0.1,1,10,100,1000,10000), limits=c(0.1,10000))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(time_1048), color = "red", linetype = "dashed", size = 1)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(time_1052), color = "red", linetype = "dashed", size = 1)+
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Max Diameter [μm]", fill = expression("Concentration " *" (#/L/"*mu*"m)")) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans="log10",breaks = c(10,100,1000), limits = c(10,1000), labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("2 min"), date_labels = "%H:%M")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1), 
        plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "cm")) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 18),  
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15),   
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15))

And the plot :
enter image description here
Do you know why my data flattened like that ?

Please provide the data. See [MRE].

On a side note: the example plot you show uses the smallest tiles for the largest particles (a consequence of the logarithmic scale), which might reverse the intended message for the casual viewer.

You can set width and height in geom_tile(), but I don't know how well it will work with a logged scale. You might have better luck with stat_density...

The "Details" section of the geom_raster / geom_tile()  seems relevent:
"geom_rect() and geom_tile()'s respond differently to scale transformations due to their parameterisation. In geom_rect(), the scale transformation is applied to the corners of the rectangles. In geom_tile(), the transformation is applied only to the centres and its size is determined after transformation"
It's hard to say what is the best strategy here.

As already mentioned in the comments the issue is due to the log scale. Instead I would suggest to use a geom_rect which however requires some manual computation.
First, let's reproduce your issue using some fake random example data:
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

set.seed(123)

dat <- expand.grid(
  x = seq(10),
  y = seq(10, 1000, length.out = 100)
)
dat$fill <- rnorm(nrow(dat))

dat |>
  ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = fill)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_y_log10()


While I also tried with setting the height in geom_tile as suggested by @GregorThomas, this does not work well. Instead a geom_rect allows for more flexibility:
dat |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    ylead = abs(y - dplyr::lead(y)),
    ylag = abs(y - dplyr::lag(y)),
    ymax = y + .5 * dplyr::coalesce(ylead, ylag),
    ymin = y - .5 * dplyr::coalesce(ylag, ylead),
    # Restrict lower bound to avoid the values from getting dropped
    ymin = if_else(ymin <= 0, 1, ymin),
    .by = x
  ) |>
  ggplot(aes(fill = fill)) +
  geom_rect(
    aes(
      xmin = x - .5, xmax = x + .5,
      ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax
    )
  ) +
  scale_y_log10(
    breaks = c(10, 100, 1000),
    labels = scales::label_log()
  )


